# Framer Motion and MUI Button Fade In Animation

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

In my react application I want display a button with a fade in effect when the page loads.
I am using framer-motion, but I can not make the animation work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion"

<AnimatePresence>
<Button component={motion.div} 
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }} 
        animate={{ opacity: 1, duration:1000 }} 
        type="submit" 
        variant="outlined" size="medium">
Continue
</Button>
</AnimatePresence>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put the duration in the transition prop of your Button ?

```
transition={{ duration: 1 }}
```

Don't forget that the duration is in seconds.

And, with the code you wrote, the AnimatePresence doesn't do anything since it is used for components that will be removed from the dom.